# Detectar ruta al presionar menu

Tags: php, laravel

soy un poco nueva en laravel y estoy confundida en como hacer esto: Tengo un menú con sus rutas respectivas y llamando a mi controlador, sucede que el menú es el mismo pero va cambiando según los permisos de usuarios que ingresen

```
    @php
       $user=\App\Administracion::where("id", "=", \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()
       ->id)->first();
   @endphp
   @if($user->tipo==40)
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{route('admin.detalle')}}" class="nav-link"><span> Detalle Gerencia</span></a>
      </li>
   @endif
   @if($user->id_tipo==20 or $user->id_tipo==30 or $user->id_tipo==40)
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{route('admin.detalle_user')}}" class="nav-link"><span> Detalle Usuarios</span></a>
      </li>
   @endif
   @if($user->id_tipo==20 or $user->id_tipo==40)
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{route('admin.detalle_planta')}}" class="nav-link"><span> Detalle Planta</span></a>
      </li>
   @endif
```

Mi rutas son las siguientes

```
Route::prefix('/administracion')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/detalle', 'AdminController@list')->name('admin.detalle');
   Route::get('/user/detalle', 'AdminController@list')->name('admin.detalle_user');
   Route::get('/planta/detalle', 'AdminController@list')->name('admin.detalle_planta');
}
```

Y mi controlador

```
public function listado(Request $request){
    if (!$request->session()->has('usuarios')) {
       return redirect()->route('index');
    }
    $usuarios=Session::get("usuarios");
    $listados = DetalleUser::where('id', '=', $usuarios)
    return view('detalle')->with(array("usuarios"=>$usuarios));
}
```

Mi pregunta viene aca, porque necesito saber o detectar por que ruta ingreso, ya que todas mis rutas llaman a la misma funcion, por ejemplo, si yo entro como perfil de superusario puedo ver los menú de Detalle de Gerencia, Detalle de usuarios, Detalle de planta, si entro con el perfil de usuario puedo ver
los menú de Detalle de usuario y Detalle de Planta y si entro con el perfil planta, solo puedo ver solo el menú de Detalle Planta.  Cuando llamo al controlador, necesito saber desde que ruta vengo para poder darle a mi variable `$listado` la validación de corresponda.  Es posible saber que menú presione?

Gracais

Comment: Puedes probar con `$uri = $request->path();`, que te devolvería `detalle`, `user/detalle` o `planta/detalle`. O aquí hay otros métodos del request que podrías usar https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#request-path-and-method

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar, me habían comentado que con prefix también lo podía hacer, he probado $request->route()->getPrefix() pero me trae administracion, he probado también como $request->route()->prefix(), lo cual me marca en la url /user/detalle pero me arroja error Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\Route::prefix(), 0 passed, lo cual me indica que estoy haciendolo mal

Comment: Sí, hay varios métodos que podrías usar del request, aquí podrás verlos todos: [Request](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html). Como tus rutas tienen nombres tambíen puedes usarlos `if ( $request->routeIs('admin.detalle_planta') ) {...}`

Comment: Para lo que dices de los métodos de route, puedes verlos aquí: [Route](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html). Verás que [prefix](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_prefix) es para asignar un prefix a la ruta, no para obtenerlo

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias! utilice $request->path() y no tuve ningún problema, mil gracias